# Context Providers using idPattern or isPattern=true

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm trying to declare one general Context Provider for all entities of the same type. The examples I have been seing defines the context providers just for one element of a collection, and it seems that is not possible define a pattern for that. In fact, the use of idPattern at Context Provider declaration time seems not to be allowed.

Other related problem is that the forwarding from orion to the context provider is not containing the same payload, loosing the restriction section.

I'm doing something wrong?

I tried diferent ways, below there is an example.

```
http://10.174.123.243:1026/v1/registry/registerContext
{
    "contextRegistrations": [
        {
            "entities": [
                {
            "type": "DATO_METEREOLOGICO",
            "isPattern": "true",
            "id": ".*"

                }
            ],
            "providingApplication": "http://10.174.123.210:8080/smarnet/observaciones"
        }
    ],
    "duration": "P1M" 
}
```

In ORION log the  "isPattern": "true" is replaced for  "isPattern": "false" and it just fordwards when the id is equals to '.*'

We're using ORION version 1.2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you edit your post to incude the Orion version you are using (i.e. the output of `contextBroker --version` command), please? Thanks!

Comment: Done, we are using version 1.2.0 of ORION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently entity patterns are not supported in Context Broker registrations. [Documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user/context_providers/index.html) has been updated to make it clear:

> In NGSIv1 registrations, `isPattern` cannot be set to `"true"`. If so, the registration fails and an error is returned. The OMA specification allows for regular expressions in entity id in registrations but as of now, the Context Broker doesn't support this feature.

In fact, in Orion 1.2.0 that error return logic is failing due to [a bug](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2332). Due to this, a registration is created (but without pattern interpretation) instead of responding with an error. The bugfix has been already implemented in develop branch and will be included in next Orion version (1.3.0).